# Where can I find documentation of gasnet collectives

Tags: gasnet

I am writing a distributed-shared memory library using GASNET_SEGMENT_EVERYTHING, and for that I need to communicate the address of an allocation from some root node to all other nodes, like an MPI_Bcast. However, I am having a tough time understanding how to implement this. Can someone give me an example on how to mimic MPI_Send with active messages, or explain how the undocumented `gasnet_coll_broadcast` from `gasnet_coll.h` works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best source of information for the GASNet collectives API in the current GASNet-EX release is the [GASNet-EX specification](https://gasnet.lbl.gov/docs/GASNet-EX.txt) (search for the section entitled `// Collectives (Coll)`).

Here's a simple example of initiating a non-blocking broadcast operation and then synchronously awaiting its completion:

```cpp
gex_Event_Wait(gex_Coll_BroadcastNB(myteam, root_rank, dstmem, srcmem, payloadsz, 0));
```

The example above is taken from the [GASNet test testcollperf](https://gasnet.lbl.gov/dist-ex/tests/testcollperf.c), and there are other examples in [GASNet test testcoll](https://gasnet.lbl.gov/dist-ex/tests/testcoll.c); although these tests are respectively written as a performance microbenchmark and a correctness validation test (and not really intended to serve as example codes).